# Is there a way to route certain internet connections through Wi-Fi when connected to wired (Windows)?

Tags: windows, networking, internet, routing

I have wired and wireless internet connections available by different ISPs, however one service is only accessible via WiFi.Is there a way to route all connections to this service through available WiFi connection (or route all traffic of the specified program), while having everything else go through wired?
I'm on Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

route ADD destination_network MASK subnet_mask  gateway_ip metric_cost

The smallest subnet mask wins

google pings out to 216.58.192.164

whois says google own 216.58.192.0-233.255

```
route add 215.58.192.0 255.255.224.0  "ip of gateway for the wireless network"
```